# Java: Double Datatype Decimal format commas issue

Tags: java

I'm solving a problem with math.pow function when the answer appear on text field with any enter value such as 10.It will be appear in commas.I use a decimal format library but nothing happen.Is there a different way to do that.I want answer like this

```
10000000000
Not
10,000,000,000
```

Code:

```
    public class Gra extends JFrame{
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("");
    public Gra(){
        super("Frame");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(163, 206, 122, 28);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(163, 106, 122, 28);
        getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEnterValue = new JLabel("Enter Value");
        lblEnterValue.setBounds(183, 89, 69, 16);
        getContentPane().add(lblEnterValue);

        JLabel lblAnswer = new JLabel("Answer");
        lblAnswer.setBounds(195, 187, 55, 16);
        getContentPane().add(lblAnswer);

        JButton btnClick = new JButton("Click");
        btnClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                double num,ans;
            String w=   textField_1.getText();
            num = Double.parseDouble(w);
            ans=Math.pow(num, 10);
            textField.setText(""+d.format(ans));


            }
        });
        btnClick.setBounds(183, 249, 90, 28);
        getContentPane().add(btnClick);


    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gra obj=new Gra();
        obj.setSize(450, 400);
        obj.setResizable(false);

        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(obj.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try digging into java.text.DecimalFormat with appropriate Locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be of some help

```
import java.text.*;
class Test {
        public static void main(String... args) {
                String  p = "10000000000";
                Double amount = Double.parseDouble(p);
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,###,###,###");
                System.out.println(df.format(amount));
        }
}
```